# Spring 3.2 - how to inject FlatFileItemWriter configured in XML to parameterized property in java class

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, spring-batch, autowired, xml-configuration

We have a current application that uses a FlatFileItemWriter configured in XML to produce a fixed length record file ("FileItemWriter"). We want to add second ItemWriter as a Java class that will process the same chunks to update a hstory table in the DB ("HistoryItemWriter"). A third Java ItemWriter ("DispatcherItemWriter") has been imnplemented to call each of these guys in turn, passing the chunk.

The problem is injecting the reference to the FlatFileItemWriter configured in XML to a FlatFileItemWriter property in the DispatcherItemWriter class. The log shows the bean reference being retrieved but it then throws a ConversionNotSupportedexception (log snippet below).

The FlatFileItemWriter property in the DispatcherItemWriter Java class was defined as parameterized, but there is no way to similarly denote parameterization in XML, though at least one post suggests this is possible in 4.0 (which is not an option for now).

I've tried a variety of approaches using @Autowired, @Resource and no annotation, coupled with defining the property with and without parameterization, and also have tried both 'p:fileItemWriter-ref="fileItemWriter"' on the bean and 'property name="fileItemWriter" ref="fileItemWriter"' within the bean. Spring finds the bean ok, but always fails with "no matching editors or conversion strategy found".

Has anyone accomplished this in 3.2?

Here is the fileItemWriter configuration:

```
<bean id="fileItemWriter" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" 
    scope="step">
    <property  name="resource" value="file:${strRunFileName}" /> 
    <property  name="lineAggregator">
    . . . etc.
    </property >
</bean>
```

Here is the dispatcherItemWriter bean configuration:

```
<bean id="dispatcherItemWriter" 
    class="com.xyz.DispatcherItemWriter" 
    scope="step">
    <property name="fileItemWriter" ref="fileItemWriter" />
</bean>
```

Here is the historyItemWriter configuration:

```
<bean id="historyItemWriter" 
    class="com.xyz.HistoryItemWriter" 
    scope="step" 
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
```

Here is the variable declaration in the HistoryItemWriter class:

```
    @Component
    public class RejectItemWriter implements ItemWriter<RejectResult> {
        // fileItemWriter is defined in module-context.xml
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        // @Autowired
        @Resource(name="fileItemWriter")
        // private FlatFileItemWriter <Result> fileItemWriter;
        private FlatFileItemWriter fileItemWriter;
```

Here is the Tasklet:

```
<batch:tasklet>
    <batch:chunk 
        reader="itemReader" 
        processor="ItemProcessor" 
        writer="dispatcherItemWriter" 
        commit-interval="1000" />
</batch:tasklet>
```

And here is the relevant part of the log:

```
16:31:48.342 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - 
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fileItemWriter'
16:31:48.342 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - 
Failed to convert bean 'fileItemWriter' 
to required type 
[org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter]
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert value of type 'sun.proxy.$Proxy10 implementing 
org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,
org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter,
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,
java.io.Serializable,
org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,
org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,
org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' 
to required type 
'org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [sun.proxy.$Proxy10 implementing 
org.springframework.batch.item.file.ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream,
org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter,
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream,
java.io.Serializable,
org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,
org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] 
to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter]: 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Note that org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter is in the list of implemented interfaces, and all the interfaces and implementing classes are parameterized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create **DispatchItemWriter**, spring batch already implemented the uses case you are looking for, use `CompositeItemWriter`. You can look for the example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/compositeItemWriterSampleJob.xml)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. Not sure why I didn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: I replaced my Java dispatcher with ComositeItemWriter. That resolved the bean creation issue, but it the log now shows "FlatFileItemWriter - Writing to flat file with 0 items.". That means FlatFileItemWriter's write() method is now being passed an empty chunk. 

Am I missing something? Here's the bean configuration: 
<bean id="compositeWriter" class="o.s.b.i.s.CompositeItemWriter"> 
  <property name="delegates"> 
    <list> 
      <ref bean="flatFileItemWriter" /> 
      (etc.)

Comment: Please update the question with entire configuration file (Issue might for some other reason as well) else first try if just single, simple fileitemwriter is working. Once the fileitemwrtier works you can then update to composite item writer

Comment: Hi @Karthik, The FlatFileItemWriter was working when it was being invoked by my java 'dispatcher' and had processed the first chunk of 1000 items; the bean configuration problem then arose on injecting the reference to the second writer which would have inserted records into a history table. I'll post the rest of the configuration in comments to follow.

Comment: Tasklet, as modified for CompositeItemWriter:
`<batch:tasklet>
    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" processor="rejectItemProcessor" writer="compositeItemWriter" commit-interval="1000" />
</batch:tasklet>`

Comment: CompositeItemWriter:
`<bean id="compositeItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter"> 
    <property name="delegates"> 
        <list> 
            <ref bean="fileItemWriter" /><!-- this guy's write method gets empty items List --> 
            <!-- ref bean="...." / --> 
        </list> 
    </property> 
</bean>`

Comment: Bizarre. I deleted all the commented-out code from prior attempts and it is now working correctly.